# Gaussian Bayesian Networks and covariance calculation

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, bayesian-network

I have difficulties in understanding the way of calculation of covariance matrix in Gaussian Bayesian Nets (from conditional to joint):

[image]

The last formula is about to calculates covariance between parent `Xi` with child `Y`, right? then what is sigma for? is `k` standing for all parents of `Y` or parents of `Xi` itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part of the theorem describes the nature of the joint distribution of $(X_1, \dots, X_k, Y)$, namely, that it is a multivariate normal distribution. Since the means of these random variables are already specified and the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ gives the covariance between all pairs $(X_i, X_j)$, all that remains is to compute the covariance of each $X_i$ with $Y$, for $i = 1, \dots, k$. The theorem says that this is a $\beta$-weighted linear combination of the $i$th row of the covariance matrix.

So to answer your three questions directly:

- Yes, the formula gives the covariance between each parent node $X_i$ and the child $Y$.
- $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix of $\mathbf{X}$.
- $k$ is the number of parents of $Y$.